# How to serialize dataset for .NET remoting (.NET Framework 3.5 SP1)?

Tags: .net, serialization, remoting

I use the binaryFormatter to serialize objects for sending. But as for the ADO.NET dataset, what is the best practice? I noticed that binary formatter is override by xmlformatter in case of dataset? how to reduce the size & increase the serialization speed?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell it to use binary-mode instead of the legacy xml mode:

```
myData.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
```

You can also try running the serializer through `GZipStream` or `DeflateStream`, but this would probably require sending it as a BLOB rather than direct remoting.

I've also done some recent work looking at pushing `DataTable` through protobuf-net, [here, including comparison metrics](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/10/datatable-life-in-old-beast.html) - even if you don't want the protobuf-tweaks, the data of numbers should help you choose between xml/binary and vanilla/gzip/deflate.

Comment: Kinda off topic, but do you know of a way to prevent the Schema being transferred on an untyped dataset?

Comment: @leppie - at a guess: `data.SchemaSerializationMode = SchemaSerializationMode.ExcludeSchema;`

Comment: Unfortunately that requires a typed dataset :(  Which I cant use in my case (MS Sync framework 1.0).

Comment: @leppie how are you doing the serialize? You can include it as a parameter if it is you calling it - `XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Sync framework (well at least the version I am stuck with) hides all those details.